# Concatenate column name and 1st row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns

```
data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c('a', 'b', 'c'), C=c(22, 21, 22))
```

I would like to combine the first row with column name as the final column name
So column A would be named "A_1" and would have values (a,22) and so on...
Can anyone help me?

[EDIT - ANSWER]
I managed this with the following:

`columns = paste(names(df),as.matrix(df[1,]))`
`columns %>% str_remove(' NA')` # to remove the "NA"'s I had in 1st row
`colnames(df) = columns`

**[Snap of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QBmW.png)**

[pseudospin output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FMG3.png)

Comment: Can you show your expected output clearly

Comment: You can get column names using :paste0(names(df),'_',df[1,,drop = T]) , but not sure what you want after that?

Comment: column A would instead be called "A_1" which is the original name "A" concatenated with the first row element of column A (value 1) and the rows after the first one would continue with their values. Is this more clear? sorry if not i can try to post some image or explain better

Comment: @KarthikS after that I want that my original dataframe have that "new" colum names as the column names, so just add your output to the original dataframe. The problem is that 1st row has also letters like "A" and with your code they are not being added as letters but as numbers (strange!)

Answer (score 5):

Possibly some confusion with rows and columns? Is this what you mean?

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1, 2, 3), B=c('a', 'b', 'c'), C=c(22, 21, 22))
colnames(df) <- paste(sep = '_', colnames(df), as.character(unlist(df[1,])))
df <- df[-1, ]
df
#>   A_1 B_a C_22
#> 2   2   b   21
#> 3   3   c   22
```

Comment: it is converting the symbols in numbers. I updated the question with the output of your code in my data. Can you check, please?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. The columns coming through as numbers are because those columns are stored as 'factors'. I edited my answer to cope with that.

Comment: And you need to be careful with the rest of the data too - it looks like numbers, but because it has been read in as a factor it's not as it seems and calculations are probably going to give weird answers.

Comment: still not working :( continue  to have numbers instead of "%" or "mg"

Comment: columns = paste(names(df),as.matrix(df[1,]))
colnames(df) = columns   this works! now i need to ignore the "NA" values

Comment: Thank you I already made it! It is in the Edit of the post :) Thanks for your help it was important!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think this may solve your problem:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df = data.frame('A' = c(NA, 1, 2),
                'B' = c('%', 6.49, 6.42),
                'C' = c('mg/l', 5.7, 8.4))
cols = df %>%
  colnames() %>%
  paste(df[1, ], sep = '_') %>%
  str_remove('_NA')

df %>%
  'colnames<-'(cols) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  apply(2, as.numeric) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

Here is the output:

```
  A  B_% C_mg/l
1 1 6.49    5.7
2 2 6.42    8.4
```

Note that it was important to remove the `NA` values from the column names in order to keep it clean.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the answer! actually I dont want the columns to have "1:ncol(.)" but instead the first row of dataframe. In the example I put 1,2,3 but my data has values in first row like "%" or "mg"

Comment: what are the values of the first row?

Comment: This is from a csv file where "," is the separator:,,,,,,,,%,mg/l,mg/l,mg/l,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,%,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg,mg/kg

Comment: can't you share your data? it's hard to help you since i don't understand what you actually mean..

Comment: yes i just updated the question with a link to the dataset snapshot

Comment: cool @user8419142, now i think i'm able to help you. i've edited my answer, check it out!

Comment: still not working :( continue to have numbers instead of "%" or "mg"

Comment: columns = paste(names(df),as.matrix(df[1,]))
colnames(df) = columns   this works! now i need to ignore the "NA" values

Comment: Thank you I already made it! It is in the Edit of the post :) Thanks for your help it was important!!!